# How to sum several .csv files ( gridded data "cells" with 145 rows and 140 columns ) to obtain csv file with same dimension

Tags: r

I have several csv files i extracted from (NetCDF format).It is online data i downloaded( monthly precipitation gridded data "cells" with 145 rows and  139 columns)
i need to sum those monthly .csv files for each year (over period 60 years) than to make a mean between 60 summations.

[ Here we go ! answer i've had ( not the smartest one but the one i worked with it)
PS: you can create a data frame with dates and aggregate to run very quickly, somehow if you have a lot of data!

1- as first step i organized  all my data by creating "repertoire" for each year with field "data" it is long way but it works! ,

2- then, i create data frame for each month, here for the first month of 1940 year

```
 df1<-read.csv2(file= "./1940-01-01.csv", sep="," , dec="." )
 df2<-read.csv2(file=   "./1940-02-01.csv", sep="," , dec="." ) 
    ...
 df12<- read.csv2(file=   "./1940-12-01.csv", sep="," , dec="." )
```

## Your data frames will be visible in the global environment

3- I SUM all my data frames ( cell by cell) to obtain as a result one data frame with 145(ROWS) and (141 COLUMNS)[ same dimension]

## For the year 1940

```
 df_1940_sum <-df1+df2+df3+df4+df5+df6+df7+df8+df9+df10+df11+df12
```

4- I made result as an output (csv file) in my repertoire

```
write.table(df_sum, file="df_1940.csv", sep= ",")
```

Comment: I suggest adding a date column to each of the imported tables and rbinding them all together into one table with `do.call(rbind, df_list)`. Then you can sum any variables after grouping by year using the date column. The example you show isn't reproducible, so that makes it hard to be more specific in terms of the actual code needed.

Comment: (1) Instead of the dreaded `get`/`assign` workflow, do `list_of_frames <- lapply(files_names, read.csv)`, then `Reduce(function(x,y)..., list_of_frames)` or something better (since that does not do what you suggest). (2) `merge` will almost always add columns to a frame, not aggregate it. Please give us a sample of at least one of the CSVs using `dput(head(x))`. (3) Unless I'm mistaken, `read.csv2(..., sep=",", dec=".") == read.csv(...)`.

Comment: @r2evans i modified my question above with a sample of my first data frame ( first and second rows)

Answer (score 1):

Three possible solutions, depending on your strict needs.

Starting with your `df`, let's create a list of three. Since is has so many columns, I'm going to focus on just a few, but the calcs are being done for all other columns.

```r
dflst <- list(df, df, df)
df[, c("X", "V1", "V20", "V21", "V34")]
#   X V1   V20   V21   V34
# 1 1 NA 63.06 36.64 11.69
# 2 2 NA 38.49 31.73    NA
```

**TL,DR:** I think "**Case 3**" is likely the best (most flexible, most robust) of the three given some assumptions, in which case you can skip this "column-name conditioning" and cases 1-2, and skip straight to the bottom.

---

### Preprocess: *Frame Conditioning*

An assumption for some of these cases is that all frames have identical dimensions and all columns are in the same order. If this is always true, then you can skip this "conditioning" step.

If it is not a safe assumption, though, one can "condition" them in a sense. I'll demonstrate with a list of three fake frames, all a little different:

```r
somelst <- list(data.frame(x=1,y=2), data.frame(y=3, x=4), data.frame(x=5, z=6))
some_names <- names(somelst[[1]])
somelst <- lapply(somelst, `[`, some_names)
# Error in `[.data.frame`(X[[i]], ...) : undefined columns selected
```

To fix this, we need to use only names that are common. Note that if this happens, then the next steps will ***silently discard*** non-standard columns.

```r
somelst <- lapply(somelst, function(l) l[, intersect(some_names, names(l)), drop=FALSE])
somelst
# [[1]]
#   x y
# 1 1 2
# [[2]]
#   x y
# 1 4 3
# [[3]]
#   x
# 1 5
```

Order of columns is now standard, but (relevant for cases 1-2 below) we have missing columns. Fix:

```r
somelst <- lapply(somelst, function(l) { l[, setdiff(some_names, names(l))] <- NA; l; })
somelst
# [[1]]
#   x y
# 1 1 2
# [[2]]
#   x y
# 1 4 3
# [[3]]
#   x  y
# 1 5 NA
```

(This last step just adds all-`NA` values for missing columns.)

So I'll apply that to our data (though we know it's a no-op here since all list elements are identical frames):

```r
df_names <- names(dflst[[1]])
dflst <- lapply(dflst, function(l) l[, intersect(df_names, names(l)), drop=FALSE])
dflst <- lapply(dflst, function(l) { l[, setdiff(df_names, names(l))] <- NA; l; })
```

---

### Case 1: `X` is data

I think this is unlikely, but I include it for completeness in case the simplest really is what is expected:

```r
out <- Reduce(`+`, dflst)
out[, c("X", "V1", "V20", "V21", "V34")]
#   X V1    V20    V21   V34
# 1 3 NA 189.18 109.92 35.07
# 2 6 NA 115.47  95.19    NA
```

---

### Case 2: `X` is a key

In this case, we just add everything together but without changing the `X` id.

**Note**: this assumes that all ids are present in all frames *and in the same order*.

```r
out <- df # really just need "X" and the right number of columns
          # ... none of the other values are used
out[,-1] <- Reduce(`+`, lapply(dflst, `[`, -1))
out[, c("X", "V1", "V20", "V21", "V34")]
#   X V1    V20    V21   V34
# 1 1 NA 189.18 109.92 35.07
# 2 2 NA 115.47  95.19    NA
```

One can verify this assumption with something like:

```r
identical(df$X, Reduce(function(a, b) if (identical(a,b)) a else FALSE, lapply(dflst, `[[`, "X")))
# [1] TRUE
```

Any difference will indicate a cause for more (not-so-simple) conditioning or **Case 3** (which is still my overall recommendation).

---

### Case 3: variable (but still important) column names

In this case, we do *not* need to pre-condition the data as we did to normalize column names and ordering, as it is taken care of naturally. It does assume that column names are important and standard, meaning that if you see `"V22"` in one frame, it means `"V22"` in all frames, and that nothing else is the same as `"V22"`.

However, it does *not* assume that all names in one frame will be in another, so absence of a column is handled smoothly. If they are all there and in the same order (as one might expect from an automated dataset), this works just as well, too.

This can be done in base-R and `data.table`, but I find the literate form of `dplyr` (and family) to be the clearest for demonstration:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

out <- map(dflst, ~ gather(., k, v, -X)) %>%
  bind_rows(.) %>%
  group_by(X, k) %>%
  summarize(v = if (all(is.na(v))) NA_real_ else sum(v, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  spread(k, v)
out[, c("X", "V1", "V20", "V21", "V34")]
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
# # Groups:   X [2]
#       X    V1   V20   V21   V34
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1    NA  189. 110.   35.1
# 2     2    NA  115.  95.2  NA
```

(This is a `tibble`, whose representation on the console has some notable differences from raw frames. Notable is that `"V20"` values appear different, though in this case this is just `tibble`'s nice way of keeping things "neat-looking" with significant digits and such. If you instead do `as.data.frame(out[, c("X", "V1", "V20", "V21", "V34")])`, you'll see that the results are the same.)

Explanation:

- `map(dflst, ...)` is doing *something* to each frame within the list;
- `gather(., k, v, -X)` is converting from "wide" to "long" format, where a single frame would like this:

  ```r
  gather(df, k, v, -X) %>% head(.)
  #   X  k  v
  # 1 1 V1 NA
  # 2 2 V1 NA
  # 3 1 V2 NA
  # 4 2 V2 NA
  # 5 1 V3 NA
  # 6 2 V3 NA
  ```
- `bind_rows(.)` is combining a list of frames into one row-concatenated frame
- `group_by(X, k) %>% summarize(...)` does the aggregation by-id and by-(original)-column, so all `X==1` and `k=="V1"` are combined into a single row, etc.
- `if (all(is.na(v))) NA_real_ else sum(v, na.rm = TRUE)` is a little bit of a hack; normally I would do *just* `sum(v, na.rm = TRUE)` (no `if`), but the other cases kept an all-`NA` field as `NA`, where this `sum` converts that to `0`. I thought it was important to keep the idea that "this field has never had data", so if all are `NA` then keep it `NA`, otherwise give the sum of all non-`NA` fields.
- `spread(k, v)` converts back from "long" to "wide" format.